# Find the PMF of variable using information from an other variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving

There are 2 people in a city. Person A is moving with probability 1/4 to city 1, with probability 1/2 to city 2, with probability 1/4 to city 3.  I create the probability mass function (PMF) of A:
   $$P_{A}(A) = 
\begin{cases}
       {\frac{1}{4}} &\quad\text{if }A =1\\
       {\frac{1}{2}} &\quad\text{if }A=2\\
       {\frac{1}{4}} &\quad\text{if }A=3
        \\ 
     \end{cases}$$

Person B follows person A in the same city with probability 1/2, otherwise with the same probability is moving to the other 2 cities.

What can we say about the PMF of person B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly notice that the probabilities of $A$ and $B$ going to different cities is given as,
$$P(B=i|A=j) = P(B=j) = \frac{1}{4}$$

For a given city $i$,
$$P(B=i) = \sum_{j}P(B=i|A=j)P(A=j)$$
Hence for $i=1$
$$P(B=1) = P(B=1|A=1)P(A=1)+ P(B=1|A=2)P(A=2)+ P(B=1|A=3)P(A=3)$$
$$P(B=1) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}$$
And solve for other i's similarly.

Answer (score 2):

You have been given information on the conditional probability of $B$ for given $A$.

Use the Law of Total Probability to evaluate the marginal probability for $B$.